# Display UIPickerView based on another UIPickerView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

I have two different `UIPickerView` where user selects the first `UIPickerView`and from the `didSelectRow` of first picker, I get the input for second `UIPickerView`. I tried setting tags for individual pickers nothing gets work. My code as follows.

```
//Picker-1
pickerView1 = [[UIpickerView alloc] init];
pickerView1 setDataSource: self];
[pickerView1 setDelegate: self];
[pickerView1 setFrame: CGRectMake(85,360,99,162)];
pickerView1.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
[pickerView1 selectRow:2 inComponent:0 animated:YES];

//Picker-2
pickerView2 = [[UIpickerView alloc] init];
pickerView2 setDataSource: self];
[pickerView2 setDelegate: self];
[pickerView2 setFrame: CGRectMake(191,360,99,162)];
pickerView2.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
[pickerView2 selectRow:2 inComponent:0 animated:YES];

//Picker -1 rows
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView{
    return 1;
}
 - (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    return getvalue1.count;
}
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component{
        return [getvalue1 objectAtIndex: row];
    } 
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{  
        NSLog(@"You selected this: %@", [getvalue1 objectAtIndex: row]);
        NSArray *getvalue2 =[getvalue1 objectAtIndex: row];

    }

//Picker-2 rows

-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView2:(UIPickerView *)pickerView{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)pickerView2:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component{  
    return getvalue2.count;
}

-(NSString *)pickerView2:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component{     
    return [getvalue2 objectAtIndex: row];
}

-(void)pickerView2:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    NSLog(@"You selected this: %@", [getvalue2 objectAtIndex: row]);
}
```

The problem is am getting the first picker values in both at the time of display. the picker 2 rows are not getting called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only have one set of picker view delegate methods. Use the `pickerView` parameter of each to do the right thing:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    if (pickerView == pickerView1) {
        return getvalue1.count;
    } else {
        return getValue2.count;
    }
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    if (pickerView == pickerView1) {
        return [getvalue1 objectAtIndex: row];
    } else {
        return [getvalue2 objectAtIndex: row];
    }
} 

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{  
    if (pickerView == pickerView1) {
        NSLog(@"You selected this: %@", [getvalue1 objectAtIndex: row]);
        NSArray *getvalue2 =[getvalue1 objectAtIndex: row];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"You selected this: %@", [getvalue2 objectAtIndex: row]);
    }
}
```

Comment: @rmaddy I tried with your code. the first one `getvalue1` of `objectAtIndex` has the array of objects without problem but the second one `getvalue2` of `objectAtIndex` in title row crashes after getting all the objects. the error i get is `-[__NSCFArray length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

Comment: Look at the data you have in your `getValue2` array. Looks like it may contain further arrays instead of strings.

Comment: @rmaddy I think i got the issue, the array looks like `getValue2( ( one), (two))`.

Comment: Yep, that's an array of arrays. Either fix the data or adjust the code to get to the desired value as needed.

Comment: @rmaddy Ya, you are right. Besides, to get the proper array do we have any syntax for array of arrays?

Comment: You could do `getValue2[row][0];`.

Comment: I achieved the array of arrays through `getvalue2 = [getvalue2 valueForKeyPath:@"@unionOfArrays.self"];`. This may help for someone.